# Jmeter the response file saved doesn't equal to total result of executed request

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm doing a performance testing with an API for download PDF file from the server. And use `Save Responses to a file` component to inspect the download file after the result is saved.
I tried to download 75 user and got all success response. But when I open the folder that I saved the result I found only 73 PDF file saved. Is there any missing configuration that I have to do to got all the result ? version I'm using is **5.4.3**.
Here is my configuration for response saved to the file.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks good.

In order to troubleshoot the issue I can only suggest:

1. Check out [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
2. Check your `report_id` variable values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) for each user as in case of duplicates the file will simply get overwritten
3. Enable [saving of response data on JMeter level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter) and inspect resulting .jtl file, first compare response sizes and then inspect response for each and every request, it might be the case the response is empty or you're getting an error while [HTTP status code is 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

Comment: I have try to save the file using something like this 
   `if(prev.getResponseCode() == "200"){
    String res=prev.getResponseDataAsString();
    vars.put("response", res);
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("logresult.csv",true);
    fstream.write(res+"\n");
    fstream.close();    
}`
 And all the response is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration looks good, but what about file name collision.
If requests are executed two quickly is it possible to have file name with exactly the same names which will result in less unique records(files).
Basically this will override the content.

Comment: The ${report_id} is the unique key generated by the server it doesn't seem like it duplicate because every thread have a unique id. Also I have try it with normal response that's not file and using ${__threadNum} as file name it still some file missing.

Comment: Interesting. Can you detect some pattern in missing files? I mean is it happening in the beginning or at the end?

Comment: It seem randomly I tried with 10 thread ramp up in 1 second, first time it miss thread [4,9], second time [2,9,10] and third time [4,7,8,9], for the fourth and fifth time I tried it with ramp up 10 second it shown all the file without any missing.

Comment: I see, may be it is combination of things but speed is def. a factor. Can you provide a sample file name?

Comment: you mean the response saved file?

Comment: yes, actual file name sample, because it bit hard to imagine it.

Comment: Just using ${__threadNum}.txt as file name. Example 1.txt, 2.txt, ...